# Using globalCompositeOperation to create gradient mask

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to use canvas's `globalCompositeOperation='destination-in'` setting to draw a series of dots that are masked by a radial gradient.  My desired outcome is shown in the screenshot below:

[image: desired outcome]

Instead, my canvas is showing the solid gradient with none of the dots visible.  Here's my JS:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
  , ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var coordMatrix = [
  [50, 100, 150, 50, 100, 150],
  [50,  50, 50, 100, 100, 100]
];

var gradient = ctx.createRadialGradient(100, 100, 0, 100, 100, 100);
gradient.addColorStop(0, 'red');
gradient.addColorStop(1, 'blue');
ctx.fillStyle = gradient;
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);

ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-in';

coordMatrix[0].forEach(function(xCoord, i) {
  var yCoord = coordMatrix[1][i];
  ctx.moveTo(xCoord, yCoord);
  ctx.arc(xCoord, yCoord, 10, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
});
```

And here's a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/73d9jawn/2/

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to call `ctx.fill()` after setting the coordinates for the arcs. Also, you need to call `ctx.fill()` after the `forEach` has completed all iterations, otherwise `globalCompositeOperation` only applies to the first circle drawn. [Here is an updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/73d9jawn/5/).